# Secure files from being downloaded by using the absolute path in the URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis

in my MVC 3 project I have a folder in the project's root where I store some SWF files. The problem is, when I hit the url in the browser's address bar, e.g

```
localhost:39217/Files/fg/f_l1.swf
```

obviously I see the download dialog. Is there any way to prevent it ? In the other words, that file would be visible in my page after the DOM is loaded, but if I just type its URL I don't want it to be downloaded. I'm afraid that both scenarios are threated the same in the IIS. Any ideas ?

Comment: What's the reason of such requirement? Seems like pseudo-security.

Comment: it's my client's requirement. The SWF file can be shown in the browser but it can't be downloaded. In that scenarios the URL to the file is the same

Comment: You can't show swf in the browser without downloading it first. Even if the user open the page in a 'proper' way, he will be able to find the SFW file in the browser's cache.

Answer (score 1):

One way I can see to solve this issue is *don't reveal the real physical path to the user*. Basically you should deliver the SWF files from a *controller action*.

If you are embedding the SWF file through object tag then the object tag will refer to this action passing the filename. You can control the action by `Authorize` attribute or some other ways and once you see the request is properly authorized then you write the flash file into the response.

The idea is clearly explained [here](http://ryanfait.com/resources/protect-flash-files-from-download/) though the code is in PHP you can migrate that to MVC.

**UPDATE:**

If you don't want to change the SWF file path then you have to do little more work in Global.asax.cs.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Javascript/{*catchall}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*catchall}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("Scripts/{*catchall}");

routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

routes.MapRoute("", "Files/Flash/{file}", new { controller = "File", action = "Flash" });
```

Now eventhough some one tries to access the SWF file directly knowing the path, the requests are handled by the `Flash` action of `File` controller and there you can do the necessary auth. check before sending back the SWF.